# Retrieving using HashMap

Tags: java, hashmap

I am trying to retrieve all the customer's Information from the main. I have a class CustomerManager and a class main (which is the: main(String[] args)) 
this is the code of CustomerManager class which is using a hashmap as a collection
public class CustomerManager {

```
private static final Map<String, Customer> customersManager = new HashMap<> ();

  public static void addCustomer(Customer c){
       // Customers
    customersManager.put(c.getID(), c);
    customersManager.put ("ID1", new Customer ("ID1","Jonathan", "Mifsud", "Test Address", 21345678, "L001"));
    customersManager.put ("ID2", new Customer ("ID2","David", "Aguis", "2nd Address", 21456778, "L002"));
    customersManager.put ("ID3", new Customer ("ID3","Frank", "Mamo", "example Address", 21987653, "L003"));
  }

  public static void findCustomer(Customer c){
     customersManager.put(c.getID(), c);
  }

  public static void deleteCustomer(Customer c){
      customersManager.remove(c.getID());
  }
```

}

 now how can I retrieve the customer information from the CustomerManagement class to the main. I tried this:
System.out.println("Insert Customer ID: ");
customersManager.findCustomer(c);
but its giving me an error:
 variable c might not have been initialized

Comment: Describe the specific problem you have and reduce the posted code to the parts associated with it, so we can help you

Comment: What's the problem? Don't forget to override the `toString` method if you want a decent String representation for your `Customer` class.

Comment: Don't think it's necessary, but you should add parameters to new HashMap<>(), just as a convention:

Map(String, Customer> customers = new HashMap<String, Customer>();

Comment: @derstrom8 some quality tools (like PMD) tells it it better to use the diamond operator `<>` for readability

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the following `toString()` method in the `Customer` class to print its content:

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Customer [fname=" + fname 
        +", lname=" + lname 
        +", address=" + address 
        +", phone=" + phone
        +", loyaltyCard=" + loyaltyCard + "]";
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the toString() method, but the problem is in the main on customers.put. the console is telling me non-static-variable this cannot be referenced from a static context